# Is this a correct way to manipulate the elements of a C++ container?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, iterator, containers

I have a `map` of the form `map<long, class>` and I search for an element on the long, returning a result of the form `pair<bool, class&>` - the bool indicating whether or not the reference is valid.

The reference is from the iterator ie., of the form `it->second` where `it` is the iterator that points to the `map` element that has the correct `long`.

I then go on, in another function, to manipulate the reference to the class instance.

So my questions are:

- Is this a valid way to return a reference?
- And will manipulating the referenced object alter the element contained in the map?

Apologies in advance if these seem like stupid questions: I thought the answers were plain but my code in misbehaving and so I am trying to plug all the possible gaps.

Comment: Should this stay valid if the `map` is changed?

Comment: As a sidenode: use `myMap.find(longValue)` to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As long as the reference is only used when the bool flag is true, and the referenced object is not removed from the map.

2) Although I'd call this technically valid, I wouldn't do this way. Instead of a bool and a reference, I'd pass a pointer to the class, with `nullptr` indicating that the class instance was not found in the map.

3) Yes, modifying the referenced/pointed to instance will modify the object in the map; as long as, somewhere along the way you didn't accidentally make a copy of the object, and are now referring to the copy, rather than the original object in the map.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a valid way to return a reference?

No. You can't create an "invalid reference" if there's no object to refer to; so you'd need to mess around with a dummy object to refer to in that case.

Return a pointer. It's simpler, smaller, less surprising and (most importantly) can legitimately be null if there's no object to point to.

> And will manipulating the referenced object alter the element contained in the map?

Yes; a reference or pointer to the map element can be use to manipulate that element.

Comment: I do return a dummy if it's false.

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin: In that case it's valid; just weird, inefficient and over-complicated.